# The cast to value type 'System.Single' failed because the materialized value is null for stored procedure

Tags: asp.net-mvc, linq, asp.net-mvc-4

My stored procedure returns the following data:

```
SensorNodeUUID         Type  val0   val1    val2
--------------------------------------------------
88418344615647248       3   25.77   0       4.23
88418344615634456       3   NULL    NULL    NULL
88432552356623423       2   NULL    NULL    NULL
88418344584627440       3   24.77   0       4.29
```

I have a model :

```
  public class EditSensorModel 
    {
        public List<EditSensorModel> editsensor;

        public Int64 SensorNodeUUID { get; set; }
        public int Type { get; set; }
        public float val0 { get; set; }
        public float val1 { get; set; }
        public float val2 { get; set; }
}
```

In the controller:

```
List<EditSensorModel> vendlist = new List<EditSensorModel>();
        var vnlist = entities.Database.SqlQuery<EditSensorModel>("exec usp_getsensornode @userid",
            new SqlParameter("@userid", Convert.ToInt32(Session["Userid"]))
     ).ToList();

                    foreach (var item in vnlist)
                    {
                    EditSensorModel temp = new EditSensorModel();
                    temp.SensorNodeUUID = item.SensorNodeUUID;
                    temp.Type = item.Type;
                    temp.val0 = item.val0 ;
                    temp.val1 = item.val1 ;
                    temp.val2 = item.val2 ;
                    vendlist.Add(temp);
                    }
```

In the controller, I am getting an error storing the data into the variable vnlist.
The error I'm facing is: The cast to value type 'System.Single' failed because the materialized value is null.
Does anyone know how to solve this error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use float? in your model.

```
float? val0;
float? val1;
float? val2;
```